# Error message : "Assertion 't = find_next_time_event( m )' failed at pulse/mainloop.c" ?...(C++)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Ok so I'm using CodeBlocks for programming in C++ . I have so "random" (it doesn't happen everytime, and I'm not able to predict when it happens) error message which makes the program crash, it says :

```
Assertion 't = find_next_time_event( m )' failed at pulse/mainloop.c:721, 
function calc_next_timeout() . Aborting .
Aborted (core dumped) .
Process returned 134 (0x86)
```

Core dumped is when I should not have deleted some pointer, am I right?

The thing I don't understand is what is before "Aborted, core dumepd" . Can it guide me to which kind of error I made ? 
Or is it a problem with CodeBlocks (I doubt it , but that could be great :p)

*I don't put code here because I just want information about what could theorically create this kind of message . Then I'll search and if I've problems with finding the error(s), I'll put some code here ;) *

Comment: [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) somewhere? And no it doesn't only happen when you're deleting a pointer, it can happen anywhere. Also read about the [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) function. And learn how to use a debugger. And build with more warning enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is telling you that an [assertion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) failed on line 721 of the file pulse/mainloop.c that is part of your source code.

An assertion is typically placed to check invariants or preconditions/postconditions. Taking a precondition as an example, this is saying "this expression has to be true in order for the code below to work correctly".

By inspecting the condition (at line 721 of mainloop.c) and understanding why it was not true in your case, you should be able to find an error in your code that lead to the failed assertion.

Comment: Ok thanks...but hte problem now is that I have no file in my project name "mainloop.c" , and no directory named "pulse", and no method named calc_next_timeout ! So I don't understand :/

Comment: @PtitSualty That's why you should learn how to use a debugger. If you run the program in a debugger, or use the core-dump (basically a memory-dump of the process at the time of the crash)  with a debugger, then the debugger will tell you where that problem is, and let you walk up the function call stack to *your* code.

Comment: You're breaking an invariant in pulseaudio. See [here](https://github.com/otcshare/pulseaudio/blob/master/src/pulse/mainloop.c#L722). It seems you haven't set a timer in a case where a timer is required to be set. I think it's where you're waiting for a timer, and since there is no timer, the code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution but this issue actually has to do with PulseAudio.  I assume OP is using Linux, possibly Ubuntu, which is when this error occurs.  I sometimes get the same thing when using a program written in Python.  There is a noted bug about this issue in the PulseAudio Launchpad bugs.

Comment: You should link the bug report.

Comment: @Gramps, is this the correct bug report? https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1451614

Comment: It has been a while but give the time frame of my comment and the link you provided, I would say this is the issue.  I was working with Pygame a lot back then.